# Loading React 15.4 with System.js fails with "require is not defined" error

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, systemjs

I've been using System.js to load my React 15.3.2 dependency into my application:

```
System.config({
    "defaultJSExtensions": false,
    "map": {
        "react": "vendor/assets/react/react.js",
        "react-dom": "vendor/assets/react/react-dom.js"
    }
});

System.import("js/main.js");
```

My main.js is importing React:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

With version 15.3.2 everything works fine. I'm able to create components, render them etc.

With version 15.4 System.js fails with an error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) require is not defined
```

I'm using Babel with `es2015` prefix.

It seems like the React 15.4 structure is completely different and ReactDOM cannot be loaded the same way as before?

Comment: From the release notes it seems like there should be no difference if you're not using private APIs: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/11/16/react-v15.4.0.html

Comment: Yes, I read that. But apparently it's not the case in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Read more about this issue here:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8301

Comment: Issue is fixed in 15.4.1